# Trying to get the Column Values in 1 sheet to other sheet in Row with Dynamic Updation from 1st sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to get the above data which is presented datewise in Column form to be pasted in the below format in Row form, but challenge is either 1 date at a time can be taken or either single cell reference needs to be given in each cell on other sheet, need some shortcut such that sheets data remains dynamic and datewise data is copied. Image shows it in one sheet, above data is required to be shown in  below format in other sheet.

[image: Excel snapshot]

Thanks and Regards
Mandeep Goraya

Comment: Have tried anything by yourself? If so, please show us.

Answer (score 0):

For example, your table is like this:

[image: 1]

Put this code into cell `B8` then fill right:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$3,MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1+ROWS($B$2:$F$3),ROWS($B$2:$F$3))+1,1+INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/ROWS($B$2:$F$3)))
```